# Basis Functions in Polynomial regression?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, polynomials

Given a set of data points **(x1,y1),...(xn,yn)**, suppose we wish to approximate these data points with a **polynomial function**. However, what would be the *highest degree* of the polynomial that we could use to approximate the data (viewed as a polynomial regression problem)? I am trying to think of this in terms of basis functions but don't understand if you can have multiple basis functions with only one independent variable.

Comment: A constant (0th degree polynomial) can match one value, so a `n-1`st degree polynomial could match n points. There are higher degree polynomials that work, but you only need n-1 to guarantee a fit

Answer (score 0):

1, x, x², x³... are valid basis functions. You can derive orthogonal polynomials from them, by the Gram-Schmidt process, for efficient regression.

Beware that polynomial fit does not work well for high degrees (say above 8). Prefer piecewise polynomials with continuity conditions.